# VOIP API PHP POST into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, voip

I would like some help translating this PHP code into JS. I admit that I have not worked what much with PHP before and I can't figure out how this POST request is made. Would I need to use jQuery or Node.js for this? Thanks for your time!

```
<?php

$user = ""; 
$pass= "";
$phone= ""; 
$text = ""; 
$url=urlencode("mywebsite...");

$curl_options = array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "website...",
   CURLOPT_POST => true,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "user=$user&pass=$pass&phone=$phone&text=$text&url=$url",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curl_options );
$result = curl_exec( $curl );

$response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$send_reponse=$response->result;

if ($send_reponse=='failed'){//eroare
   echo "error: ".$response->description;
}else{   echo "message sent=".$response->description;
}

?>
```

Comment: Client side or server side JS? For client side, AJAX/XHR or others. For server side, node has native support for requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I took a look at AJAX and Node but I am a bit confused how will I translate the curl stuff from PHP into JS. I need some help translating it into JS as I don't really have any knowledge of PHP.